# Is it possible to get this carousel with roundabout plugin?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-plugins, positioning, carousel

I'm using the [roundabout plugin](http://fredhq.com/projects/roundabout/) to animate a carousel, everything works, but I can't get the same rendering like in [the image](http://www.hostingpics.net/viewer.php?id=316314cleansleekwebdesign.jpg) which represents my intended carousel look while [this link](http://onsixam.cfun.fr/roundabout.html) represents my code results currently.

- http://www.hostingpics.net/viewer.php?id=316314cleansleekwebdesign.jpg
- http://onsixam.cfun.fr/roundabout.html

I played with the plugin values of the available options but unfortunately still can't get the items positioning as in the image, I'm also wondering how to set the `<li>` dimensions.

I really feel frustrated and overwheelmed and I don't know if this because I'm not clever enough or what.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#sample-roundabout').roundabout({
        tilt: 0.9,
        minScale: 1,
        maxsCale: 3,
        minOpacity: 1,
        duration: 400
    }, function() {
        $(this).fadeTo(500, 1);
    });
});
```

Comment: You should probably give us a non-static way to view your images, either the live site will do, or you could create a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net).

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the width of your ul to a smaller value, for what you're looking to get, try something like this in you CSS stylesheet:

```
#sample-roundabout{
  width: 400px;
}
```

Just play around with that value and the tilt too probably, and I don't think you'll have too hard a time getting it to work.

Comment: but how about the width of the li items , they're set automatically by the plugin.

Comment: no i think i need to alter the width, height and position of the li items dynamically .
how comes , the width of the slider that i wanna achieve is 950px , and you're asking me to reduce it to 400px !!!

Comment: even if i do so , how could i give the list items my own dimensions and not the ones set by the plugin?

Comment: You're going to have to show me the original source for the first image then too, so I can see how they did it.

Comment: there is no source for the first image , it was a hiring test that i failed  they gave me only the psd

Comment: http://fredhq.com/projects/roundabout/ and demo at http://fredhq.com/projects/roundabout/demos/standard

Comment: In that case you could always make the sliding tiles larger.

Answer (score 0):

Strictly using CSS you could do something [like this](http://jsbin.com/ezukov/1/edit#html,live): http://jsbin.com/ezukov/1/edit#html,live

```
ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 863px;
    height: 300px;
}
li {
    height: 220px;
    width: 621px;
    background-color: #ccc;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
}
    li.roundabout-in-focus {
    margin-top:50px;
    background:red;
    cursor: default;
}
```

Going further then this you can create callback functions to smoothly animate the middle slide back up before it does the lazysusan animation. Or you could create your own [roundabout shape animation](http://fredhq.com/projects/roundabout-shapes) if you want something different.

Comment: Anthony you really clarified all the ambiguity that was going on my mind , but tell me please what's  the efficient way to become able of altering any jQuery plugin  in your opinion.
thanks man , i appreciate

Comment: In this case css might solve it but it could have been solved via JS. So honestly learning javascript well is all there is to it and then read the source code of the plugins as much as you can. Sometimes you will find good coments in the actual source code of the plugin or framework that you would not find in the usual user documents. It has helped me learn lots so "Learn to Read the Source, Luke!" http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2012/04/learn-to-read-the-source-luke.html